# Tensorflow GPU on GPU cluster with 11.1 CUDA

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have access to GPU cluster, where i want to learn model using keras. First i need to install required packages.

I already tried to install tensorflow 2.3.0, tf-nighty-gpu, tensorflow-gpu, but still have error:

```
Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'
```

- My OS: CentOS 7.9
- Python version: 3.6
- GPU: 10x1080Ti

I dont have root access. Which version of TF, must be installed?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45200) helps you ?

Comment: @TFer2 solved using Anaconda